# I am getting an error when trying use Cloudinary storage, Must Supply API key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, web-applications, credentials, cloudinary

[image]

I am a student and new to Cloudinary and API credentials. I was trying to use Cloudinary storage and image upload for my app. After adding my credentials and running by command `EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit`  accidentally I pressed Control + C on Credentials.
Now when I try to upload image I get the following error. Can it be because I pressed control + c or can it be some other API key error. How can I fix this error please?

Comment: When you do these types of post, you need to remember to share parts of your code, so that we can help. Make sure to hide any api keys as these should be kept confidential.

Comment: Sure nws. Will do next time.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the app can't find your Cloudinary credentials. You can use the following page - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#configuration - to choose one of the 3 ways to supply the Cloudinary credentials (cloud_name, api_key and api_secret) in your Rails app. For example, using the `cloudinary.yml` file which you can download from your Cloudinary Dashboard directly and place it in the `config` folder inside your app's directory.

Comment: thanx for your help I finally solved it, with help from my class as well.